# Gradle compileTestJava fails during gradle clean build

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I'm currently having this strange issue with gradle build. Below are the details.

I currently have a java-spring boot based multi module gradle project in the following structure

```
  RootProjectDir
      SubProjectA
      SubProjectB
      SubProjectCommon
```

The build.gradle file of each one of projects is as below

> RootProjectDir build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile project(":SubProjectA")
 compile project(":SubProjectB")
 compile project(":SubProjectCommon")
 testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

> SubProjectA build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile project(":SubProjectCommon")

}
```

> SubProjectB build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile project(":SubProjectCommon")

}
```

> SubProjectCommon build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
 .....
 .....
}
```

When I execute the

> gradle clean build

the build is failing during the **compileTestJava** phase of SubProjectA. SubProjectA tests have compile time dependency on classes in SubProjectCommon.

If I just execute the following

> gradle :subProjectA compileTestJava

the build is successful again.

It is failing with the message that SubProjectCommon classes could not be resolved.

The strange thing is that in the IntelliJ IDEA it doesn't show any compilation issues for the SubProjectA test classes and test executes fine. Also when I just execute the

> gradle clean test

everything works fine.

I even tried putting a testCompile dependency on SubProjectCommon in the SubProjectA build.gradle like this

> SubProjectA build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
     compile project(":SubProjectCommon")
     testCompile project(":SubProjectCommon")

    }
```

but still doesn't work

PS:-I currently have written test cases only for SubProjectA classes.

Comment: I am having a similar problem with Gradle 4.1 and Spring Boot 1.5.4

Comment: I hit the same problem using gradle 6.8.3
Have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

IDEs do not honor module paths very nicely, especially Eclipse, so everything is usually included together, thus you do not get any path problems.

Gradle makes clean distinctions between different projects.

So if your classes were in the test folder, You may need to reference the test sets properly using the below:

```
 testCompile project(":SubProjectCommon").sourceSets.test.output
```

or

```
 compile project(":SubProjectCommon").sourceSets.test.output
```

depending on which sourceSet is using classes from the other project.